# Install4j - How to get current version when upgrading

Tags: java, install4j

Any one know how to determine the current installed version of an app installed with install4j.
The idea is to figure out what is installed and control if an upgrade is possible based on the version already installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ApplicationRegistry` API for that purpose. Here is an example code snippet that could be used in a "Run script" action in the "Startup" node to prevent an installation if the current version is already installed:

```
// The value returned by context.getInstallationDirectory() will be the
// last installation directory
// if the user has already installed the application
ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo applicationInfo =
    ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoByDir(context.getInstallationDirectory());

if (applicationInfo == null) {
  // The application has never been installed before
    return true;
}

// The version of this installer is contained in a system installer variable
String myVersion = (String)context.getVariable("sys.version");
if (applicationInfo.getVersion().equals(myVersion)) {
    // In that case the current version is already installed.
    Util.showErrorMessage("The current version is already installed in this directory");
    // By returning "false", the action will fail and the installer will quit.
    // Note that you have to set the "Failure strategy" property of your
    // "Run script" action to "Quit on error", otherwise the installer will continue.
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```